# How can i pass webpack environment variables in html?

Tags: webpack, environment-variables

How can i get / access webpack ENV variables during process time (not runtime in browser) ? the `webpack.DefinePlugin(...)` doesn't seem to work in html files, i don't have access to ENV variables in the main `index.html`

any solution ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use [html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin). You will have to use .ejs or some other template language and then use like that

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/public/index.ejs',
        inject: 'body',
        environment: process.env.NODE_ENV
    }),
```

in index.ejs

```
<body class="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.environment %>">
```

Comment: This is not a `HtmlWebpackPlugin` specific feature as it is not documented there, but rather something implicit by webpack, right? Wouldn't it be cleaner to not put it inside this object, but under webpack config.environment directly?

Answer (score 33):

Actually you can also use your variables from `DefinePlugin` in your ejs template, using `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.

EJS:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<%= process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID %>"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}

  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', '<%= process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID %>');
</script>
```

webpack.config.js:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID': JSON.stringify(process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID),
}),
```

(You don't have to use `process.env`, but it'll prevent your app from crashing if the variable isn't defined.)