# Access environment variables in index.html with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, environment-variables

I have a React app which has access to environment variables in the normal way using `DefinePlugin`. We are able to access these variables all throughout the app. However, we cannot access them in the static folder, namely `index.html`.

Is there any way to access environment variables in static files with Webpack/React?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902197/how-can-i-pass-webpack-environment-variables-in-html

Comment: That requires ejs which we are not allowed to use

Comment: Then I guess what you can do is to use shell script run by WebPack. The script will update the file: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `html-webpack-plugin` & `.ejs` template language

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ iw
     template: './src/public/index.ejs',
     inject: 'body',
     env: process.env.NODE_ENV
}),

<body class="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.env %>"> </body
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're correct but it's unlikely we will be allowed to use ejs